# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'martial' given input columns

Tags: apache-spark-sql

```
val martial = sqlContext.sql("select martial, count(*) as number from marketing1 where y='yes'group by martial order by number desc ")
```

Error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'martial' given input columns: [default, balance, education, duration, previous, age, loan, contact, campaig
n, poutcome, job, pdays, housing, y, marital, day, month]; line 1 pos 95
```

Is it martial column cannot resolve

Answer (score 0):

Use `column-name` for accessing any column.